# Finding a closed form for this summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, binomial-coefficients

I have been trying to derive a few identities using some bell polynomials and a technique i have come up with and i came across this summation:

$$
\rho(n,k) = \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} {\frac{-j}{2} \choose n} (-1)^{k-j}
$$

Is there a way to express this in a closed form? I tried wolframalpha but got a very weird result.

Comment: I was scrolling down StackExchange when all of the sudden it reloads and a question from Eric Lawson appears. I wish I could help you out. I should probably delete this comment before I get in trouble for being off topic.

Comment: @MatthewPereira haha dude i dont think that you will get in trouble haha